# Udev taking 15 seconds to detect mouse

Tags: udev, mouse

Whenever my mouse, a SteelSeries Xai, is plugged in, there is a 15 second delay until the mouse is properly recognized and starts working. This is specially troublesome at boot, where udev waits for 15 seconds doing nothing.

The following is the relevant information that I found on `dmesg` at boot:

```
[    1.238572] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[   16.249791] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   16.249794] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   16.250382] input: Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd. SteelSeries Gaming Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/input/input1
[   16.250463] hid-generic 0003:1038:1360.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Mouse [Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd. SteelSeries Gaming Device] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0
[   16.250608] input: Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd. SteelSeries Gaming Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.1/input/input2
[   16.250642] hid-generic 0003:1038:1360.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd. SteelSeries Gaming Device] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input1
[   16.254873] hid-generic 0003:1038:1360.0003: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Device [Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd. SteelSeries Gaming Device] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input2
```

As you can see, for 15 seconds, `udev` is doing nothing.

However, when I unplug it and then re-plug it, the process is a bit different:

```
[22660.547752] usb 6-1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
[22665.718517] input: Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd. SteelSeries Gaming Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0/input/input19
[22665.718676] hid-generic 0003:1038:1360.0004: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Mouse [Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd. SteelSeries Gaming Device] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0
[22670.724539] input: Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd. SteelSeries Gaming Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.1/input/input20
[22670.724665] hid-generic 0003:1038:1360.0005: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Keyboard [Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd. SteelSeries Gaming Device] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input1
[22675.735427] hid-generic 0003:1038:1360.0006: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Device [Ruling Technologies Sdn. Bhd. SteelSeries Gaming Device] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input2
```

Now it seems like it's recognizing parts of the mouse at 5 second intervals.

The problem might be with the mouse. I had problems with it in the past on Linux, so I won't discard it. However, I'm interested in *at least* a workaround so my boot process doesn't take so long (it's about 45s to the DE, so 15s of nothing is *a lot*). If whenever I plug it in I still have to wait 15 seconds, that's fine. The mouse works OK and doesn't reconnect by itself.

So: Is there a way to speed up the detection of a device, even if it's manually?

Or: Is there anything I can do to `udev` so it doesn't wait at boot for this particular device to respond?

Comment: did you find the solution? I have exactly the same problem

Comment: @SagarSakre Nope. Seems to be the mouse reacting very slowly to whatever the computer asks it when booting. The delay goes away when I have a Xbox 360 controller attached, though. Really strange...

Comment: Oh!! I had an older board where there was no delay, but with the other board delay is around 20 secs. hw conf, soft, os,  mouse, everything being the same. Strange. Will see if I can find an alternative through software way